# Link with negative z-index not clickable in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, z-index

Can anyone give me a hint why the link in the gray box is not clickable in Internet Explorer (I'm using version 11).

**http://jsfiddle.net/rk7n7xjj/1/**

I tested it in any other browsers and it works fine.

**HTML**

```
<div class="gray"><a href="#bla">This link is not clickable in IE</a></div>
<div class="yellow">Some placeholder text</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.gray {
position:fixed;
z-index:-1;
top:100px;
background:gray;
height:50px;
width:200px;
}

.yellow {
margin:0 auto;
background:yellow;
height:1000px;
margin-top:400px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link is not clickable becaue of the `z-index`.
Actually you setting the `div` behind the `body`. You must specify the `z-index` of the `body` too. Or at least set it positiv so it's in front of the `body` and set other elemnts higher if you expact to display them in front of the gray `div`. Thats why you cant click it.
Obviously Firefox and co has no problems to identify the link when you set `z-index` like this.

This may helps you to understand how you can use `z-index` also in IE.

[image]

In your case, to get what you want, your `CSS` should look like:

```
.gray {
    position:fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top:100px;
    background:gray;
    height:50px;
    width:200px;
}

.yellow {
    position:relative;
    z-index: 2;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:yellow;
    height:1000px;
    margin-top:400px;
}
```

Actually you dont need the `z-index` on the gray in your case but if you plan to may display something behind the gray `div` than you may need it.

Comment: The gray div should always stay behind the yellow one. If I remove the z-index or put it higher, it stays on top, which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: See my update. This may explains all you need. You just have to set the z-index right, thats all.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I got it now :)

Comment: You welcome. If this was helpful, may vote it up and accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

The link is not clickable because IE is taking it behind the body. If you notice, even the text of the link is not selectable. Try setting a `z-index: 1` to the `body` or any parent container. That ways you are first telling the browser to take all the elements inside the container to a higher z-index and then move the link behind that raised set of elements (But the movement of the link is done only within the parent's context i.e. the raised level. Read about [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)). Thus the link now becomes clickable.

**Alternate Solution**
If you just want the yellow div over the gray div, then give a positive z-index to the yellow div only. Remove the z-index property from the gray div. If no z-index value is present, 0 is taken as the default. It will always stay behind the yellow div.

```
.yellow {
     position: relative;
     z-index: 1;
     /* other styles */
 }
```